# Ionic 2: Uncaught Error: Module build failed in webpack

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Hello I am having trouble running the tabs starter app. I am doing these-

```
ionic start hetalia tabs --v2
cd hetalia
ionic serve
```

Then in the browser I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:18:34)

at Object.typescriptSourcemapLoaderMemory (H:\hetalia2\hetalia\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack\typescript-sourcemap-loader-memory.js:18:34)

at eval (webpack:///./src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts?:1:7)
at Object. (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1463:1)
at webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.ts?:4:75)
at Object. (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3184:1)
at webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.module.ts?:3:73)
at Object. (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3170:1)
at webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/main.dev.ts?:2:70)
```

Am I missing any steps? Please help

Comment: can you post the output of running `ionic info`? And try `cd hetalia && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve this?